# pip fails with ReadTimeoutError

Tags: command-line, 16.04, python3, pip

I'm trying to install `jupyter notebook` using `pip`, so I first installed `pip3`:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends python3-pip
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

While downloading the package `notebook` it waits for some seconds, then it fails with lots of errors, which end of them looks like this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 231, in _error_catcher
raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

My Ubuntu version is: 16.04 (Xenial), and I'm running on a fairly slow Internet connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `notebook` package size is around `6.9 MB` and if you running on a low speed internet connection there is a high chance that installation fails because of the timeout.

I fixed the problem by updating the `pip3`, however I'm going to suggest another way too, If it's not possible for you to upgrade the `pip3`, use this one, this would do the work too.

You can use `--default-timeout` switch to fix this issue, e.g:

```
sudo pip --default-timeout=1000 install jupyter
```

It should ignore the timeout and installation will be done with success.

---

The other thing that worked for me was updating `pip3`, the one in the Ubuntu repositories is pretty old: `8.1.1` and the last version at the time of writing this guide is: `9.0.1`. I suggest this method simply because you don't have to run `pip3` with `--default-timeout` every time that you are trying to install a new package, and of course you can use an alias too ;) whatever works for you.

By the way, I'm not a fan of installing python packages as root, so I suggest using `--user` switch to install it locally for yourself, but if you are trying to make this package wide system available, then go with `sudo`.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip --user
```

And if you get the same error, now you know how to fix it, just use `--default-timeout` switch to upgrade `pip`.

Now it should work without any error:

```
pip3 install jupyter --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue on my server by following setup because the only timeout not helped me:

~/.pip/pip.conf on ubuntu machine with content below

[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org

[install]
timeout = 100

Seems like other "more trusted" hosts fine for some network providers and now in works great.
More info in doc https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#pip-config-file